# how to manage multiple requests at once in django

Tags: django

I want to manage several event at once in django.
for example if 10-people click like button of the post , owner of the post will receive one push-notification that say "10 people liked your post", not 10 push-notifications for each clicks.
i can't get a any point to handling this. could somebody help this problem?

Comment: There is no magical way to perform this. You will need to implement a central (possibly database or cache backed) counter.

Comment: This has more to do with the architecture of your app than anything related to django!